# Select2 initSelection

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a problem to set the method initSelection with an ajax call, I returns "undefined".
I checked and the ajax call returns the correct result ..
I donot understand the method how to set the callback method to make sure that you select 'the preset value.

```
 function mediaFormatResult(media) {
        var markup = "<div class='media-title'>" + media.name + ", " + media.prov + " (" + media.region + ")</div>";

        return markup;
    }

    function mediaFormatSelection(media) {
        return media.name +", " + media.prov + " (" + media.region + ")";
    }
    $field = $('#comune');
    $($field).select2({
        placeholder: "Seleziona il tuo comune",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        initSelection: function(element, callback) {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myurl",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: (element.val())},
            success: function(data){
                //results: data.results;
            }
        }).done(function(data) { 
            //console.log(data);
            callback(data);
        });

        },
        ajax: { 
            quietMillis: 100,
            url: "myurl",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term,
                    page_limit: 10
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return {results: data.results};
            }
        },
        formatResult: mediaFormatResult, 
        formatSelection: mediaFormatSelection, 
        formatNoMatches: function () { return "Nessun risultato trovato!";},
        formatSearching: function () { return "Ricerco.."; },
        formatInputTooShort: function(input, min) {return "Inserire "+ (min - input.length) + " caratteri.";},
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
    });
```

There is something wrong?

Comment: I answered at other question. Look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/30625628/2788478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the way to solve:

```
initSelection: function(element, callback) {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: path,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: (element.val())},
            success: function(data){

            }
        })
```

care must be taken that the array is created in the controller and it should be something like this:

```
foreach ($entities as $member) {
        $json['id'] = $member->getId();
        $json['name'] = $member->getComune();
        $json['region'] = $member->getRegione()->getRegione();
        $json['prov'] = $member->getProvincia()->getSigla();
}

        $result = $json;
        return json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 12):

Pay attention, the data you send to the callback function, needs to be an object, with an **id** and **text** attributes.

This is what worked for me:

```
initSelection: function(element, callback) {
    var id;
    id = $(element).val();
    if (id !== "") {
      return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          id: id
        }
      }).done(function(data) {
        var results;
        results = [];
        results.push({
          id: data.id,
          text: data.name
        });
        callback(results[0]);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Upvoted. Not sure what the other answer achieves with an empty success handler?

Comment: The `initSelection` option has been deprecated in favor of a custom data adapter (Select2 version 4+), see https://select2.github.io/options.html.

Comment: https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35 is a link that contains useful data on the deprecation. Sort of anyway.. it's quite unhelpful really.